# Isolate contour line with a minimum number of points (to eliminate small polygons) with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour

I extracted a single contour line (altitude 3660 m) with ArcGIS. How can I eliminate small polygons ? 
I know how to do it with a GRASS command (generate contour lines) which simply asks for a minimum of points to create the contour line. I would like to know how do it with ArcGIS.

[image]

Here is a red arrow showing the contour line I want to see. The yellow arrow points the small contour lines I want to erase.

Comment: Can you add an image to your question showing exactly what you want to delete?

Comment: I added an image. The largest contour line I want to keep is actually the paleolake contour. It is flat in the middle (Salar de Uyuni).

Comment: If the contour identified by the red arrow is a single polyline, I would select it, invert the selection and run the delete features tool to delete all the selected polylines. I would work from a backup just to may sure it has worked as you expected.